# JSON GENERATE in COBOL module - need to take data from a table and have it generate into a single object with values

Tags: json, cobol, generate

I need to go from this:

15  benefitStageAmountsMap OCCURS 4 TIMES.
20 BEN-STG-QUL         PIC X(02).
20 BEN-STG-AMT         PIC S9(06)V9(02).

to this:

"benefitStageAmountsMap": {
"09": "5",
"01": "1.2",
"02": "3.4",
"03": "4.5"

without the field names associated with each table entry.

Filler is ignored by the GENERATE and creating one entry with a large enough PIC doesn't separate out the data as its expected. Cannot omit the field names since they are in a table and when defined each one separately, the omit wasn't allowed tho still checking into that.  It may be due to the large size of the structure for the GENERATE tho not sure.

Comment: It appears that you're trying to create an invalid JSON.  You may have to assemble the string output yourself with an output 01 description.  Your example output appears to be missing a closing brace.

Comment: Yes, I had grabbed this section from the middle of the JSON request and forgot to include the bracket.  I wanted to show the specific formatting - "code" : "amt" - which is creating difficulties for me to format using JSON GENERATE and reason why I'm here asking for assistance.